# Casting a column to JSON/dict and flattening JSON values in a column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I am new to Pyspark and I am figuring out how to cast a column type to dict type and then flatten that column to multiple columns using `explode`.

Here's how my dataframe looks like:

```
   col1    | col2        |
    -----------------------
    test:1  | {"test1":[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1"},{"Id":"01","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}],
{"test8":[{"Id":"1","cName":"c11","pScore":0.0},{"Id":"012","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}]
    test:2  | {"test1:subtest2":[{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]}
```

Right now, the schema of this dataframe is

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
```

The output I am looking to have is like this:

```
col1   | col2           | Id | cName | pScore  |
------------------------------------------------
test:1 | test1          | 17 | c1    | null    | 
test:1 | test1          | 01 | c2    | 0.003609|
test:1 | test8          | 1  | c11   | 0.0     |
test:1 | test8          | 012| c2    | 0.003609|
test:2 | test1:subtest2 | 18 | c13   | 0.00203 |
```

I am having trouble defining the right schema for col2 to cast its type from `String` to `json` or `dict`. And then, I would like to be able to explode the values to multiple columns as shown above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Spark 2.0 + .

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what is the structure of the JSONs in col2? Is it always going to be like `{'unique_key': [{"Id": "XX", "cName": "XX", "pScore": X.XX}, ...]}`?

Comment: @RichardNemeth: Yes, that's how it's always going to be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer, I used `udf` to put the key into array, then explode to reach the desired output

See the example below:

```py
import json
import re

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('test:1',
     '{"test1":[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1"},{"Id":"01","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}]},'
     '{"test8":[{"Id":"1","cName":"c11","pScore":0.0},{"Id":"012","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}]}'),
    ('test:2', '{"test1:subtest2":[{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]}')
], ['col1', 'col2'])

schema = ArrayType(
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("Col", StringType()),
            StructField("Id", StringType()),
            StructField("cName", StringType()),
            StructField("pScore", DoubleType())
        ]
    )
)


@f.udf(returnType=schema)
def parse_col(column):
    updated_values = []

    for it in re.finditer(r'{.*?}]}', column):
        parse = json.loads(it.group())
        for key, values in parse.items():
            for value in values:
                value['Col'] = key
                updated_values.append(value)

    return updated_values


df = df \
    .withColumn('tmp', parse_col(f.col('col2'))) \
    .withColumn('tmp', f.explode(f.col('tmp'))) \
    .select(f.col('col1'),
            f.col('tmp').Col.alias('col2'),
            f.col('tmp').Id.alias('Id'),
            f.col('tmp').cName.alias('cName'),
            f.col('tmp').pScore.alias('pScore'))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
|  col1|          col2| Id|cName|  pScore|
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
|test:1|         test1| 17|   c1|    null|
|test:1|         test1| 01|   c2|0.003609|
|test:1|         test8|  1|  c11|     0.0|
|test:1|         test8|012|   c2|0.003609|
|test:2|test1:subtest2| 18|  c13| 0.00203|
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Hi! do you happen to know how I can tweak this code to parse more key-value pairs in col2? Currently, the code only extracts first key and first value.

Comment: Could you edit your question and show all desired outputs?

Comment: Yes, I can. Please give me a sec

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question with the right input dataframe and expected output dataframe. Please let me know if need more info

Comment: Done, look my answer again

Answer (score 1):

Because of the different key name for each row in the JSON, defining a general schema for the json is not going to work well, I believe it's better to handle this via UDFs:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t
from pyspark.sql import Row
import json

def extract_key(dumped_json):
    """
    Extracts the single key from the dumped json (as a string).
    """
    if dumped_json is None:
        return None

    d = json.loads(dumped_json)

    try:
        return list(d.keys())[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

def extract_values(dumped_json):
    """
    Extracts the single array value from the dumped json and parses each element
    of the array as a spark Row.
    """
    if dumped_json is None:
        return None

    d = json.loads(dumped_json)
    try:
        return [Row(**_d) for _d in list(d.values())[0]]
    except IndexError:
        return None

# Definition of the output type of the `extract_values` function
output_values_type = t.ArrayType(t.StructType(
 [t.StructField("Id", t.StringType()), 
  t.StructField("cName", t.StringType()), 
  t.StructField("pScore", t.DoubleType())]
))

# Define UDFs
extract_key_udf = f.udf(extract_key, t.StringType())
extract_values_udf = f.udf(extract_values, output_values_type)

# Extract values and keys
extracted_df = df.withColumn("values", extract_values_udf("col2")). \
 withColumn("col2", extract_key_udf("col2"))
# Explode the array
exploded_df = extracted_df.withColumn("values", f.explode("values"))

# Select the wanted columns
final_df = exploded_df.select("col1", "col2", "values.Id", "values.cName", 
                              "values.pScore")
```

The result is then as wanted:

```
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
|col1  |col2          |Id |cName|pScore  |
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
|test:1|test1:subtest1|17 |c1   |0.002034|
|test:1|test1:subtest1|01 |c2   |0.003609|
|test:2|test1:subtest2|18 |c13  |0.00203 |
+------+--------------+---+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful solution. It works as expected. What happens if one of the keys is missing in some of the dictionaries?

Comment: The error handlers were missing, I've just added them.

Comment: Hey Richard, do you happen to know how I can tweak this code to parse more key-value pairs in `col2`? Currently, the code only extracts first key and first value.

Comment: That is exactly why I asked you beforehand whether the json structure is always going to be like `{'unique_key': [{"Id": "XX", "cName": "XX", "pScore": X.XX}, ...]}`, because if not, then it is a bit more problematic. If you know beforehand what keys are going to be present in the root, you can handle that just fine. If not, the best way would probably be to return array of keys `list(d.keys())` and array of array of rows `[[Row(**_d) for _d in x] for x in list(d.values())]`. But there is still some caution required before calling the explode method.

Comment: I tried doing this. But it threw some weird error. Now, I am stuck at this phase. I don't know what keys would be present in the root.

Comment: If you changed the output type, remember to update the output types accordingly, i.e. for the udf `extract_key` the output type will be `t.ArrayType(t.StringType())` and for the udf `extract_values` the output type will now be `t.ArrayType(t.ArrayType(t.StructType(
 [t.StructField("Id", t.StringType()), 
  t.StructField("cName", t.StringType()), 
  t.StructField("pScore", t.DoubleType())]
)))`

Comment: TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list . I keep getting this error :(

Comment: That means that the part `Row(**_d)` is failing, because `_d` is not a dictionary, but a list apparently. Can you check what are the values in the JSON?

Comment: Yes, `d.values()` will now be `[[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1","pScore":0.002034},{"Id":"01","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}], [{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]]`. `d.values()` will now be a list of lists since we're not querying just the 0th index.

Comment: For that case `[[Row(**_d) for _d in x] for x in list(d.values())]` this works just fine, where `list(d.values())` is exactly `[[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1","pScore":0.002034},{"Id":"01","cName":"c2","pScore":0.003609}], [{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]]`.

Comment: I tried that. But that just returns all columns in the form of a big list. Doesn't really explode the values the way I want them to. Isn't there any other way to do this? Like `from_json`?