# Read one column as json strings and another as regular using pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1    | col2        |
-----------------------
test:1  | {"test1:subtest1":[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1"}], "test1:subtest2":[{"Id":"01","cName":"c2"}]}
test:2  | {"test1:subtest2":[{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]}
```

I want an output like this:

```
col1   | col2           | Id | cName | pScore  |
------------------------------------------------
test:1 | test1:subtest1 | 17 | c1    | null    | 
test:1 | test1:subtest2 | 01 | c2    | null    | 
test:2 | test1:subtest2 | 18 | c13   | 0.00203 |
```

This is a follow up to this question - [Casting a column to JSON/dict and flattening JSON values in a column in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409454/casting-a-column-to-json-dict-and-flattening-json-values-in-a-column-in-pyspark/56409889?noredirect=1#comment99918287_56409889)

I am new to pyspark and would appreciate any help on this. I tried the solution given in that post. It kept giving me errors

```
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

I also tried the following:

```
test = sqlContext.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.col2))
```

But this gave me an output like the following:

```
 test1:subtest1      | test1:subtest2        |
----------------------------------------------
[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1"}] | [{"Id":"01","cName":"c2"}]
null                       | [{"Id":"18","cName":"c13","pScore":0.00203}]
```

I am stuck at how I can use the ^ above to join to `col1` and get the desired output.

Any help is much much appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **from_json()** function, the key is to define the json_schema which you can manually create it or if you are using the pyspark 2.4+, you can use the function [schema_of_json()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json) (below code tested under *pyspark 2.4.0*):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# define all keys with a list:
my_keys = ['test1:subtest1', 'test1:subtest2']

# find a sample json_code for a single key with all sub-fields and then construct its json_schema
key_schema = df.select(F.schema_of_json('{"test1:subtest1":[{"Id":"17","cName":"c1","pScore":0.00203}]}').alias('schema')).first().schema

>>> key_schema
u'struct<test1:subtest1:array<struct<Id:string,cName:string,pScore:double>>>'

# use the above sample key_schema to create the json_schema for all keys
schema = u'struct<' + ','.join([r'`{}`:array<struct<Id:string,cName:string,pScore:double>>'.format(k) for k in my_keys]) + r'>'

>>> schema 
u'struct<`test1:subtest1`:array<struct<Id:string,cName:string,pScore:double>>,`test1:subtest2`:array<struct<Id:string,cName:string,pScore:double>>>'
```

**Note:** backticks are required to surround the fieldname when it contains special characters like **`:`**.

After we have the schema, the json data can be retrieved from the `col2`:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('data', F.from_json('col2', schema)).select('col1', 'data.*')

>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test1:subtest1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pScore: double (nullable = true)
 |-- test1:subtest2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pScore: double (nullable = true)

>>> df1.show(2,0)
+------+--------------+--------------------+
|col1  |test1:subtest1|test1:subtest2      |
+------+--------------+--------------------+
|test:1|[[17, c1,]]   |[[01, c2,]]         |
|test:2|null          |[[18, c13, 0.00203]]|
+------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Then you can use select and union to normalize the dataframe:

```
df_new = df1.select('col1', F.lit('test1:subtest1').alias('col2'), F.explode(F.col('test1:subtest1')).alias('arr')) \
            .union(
                df1.select('col1', F.lit('test1:subtest2'), F.explode(F.col('test1:subtest2')))
           ).select('col1', 'col2', 'arr.*')  

>>> df_new.show()
+------+--------------+---+-----+-------+
|  col1|          col2| Id|cName| pScore|
+------+--------------+---+-----+-------+
|test:1|test1:subtest1| 17|   c1|   null|
|test:1|test1:subtest2| 01|   c2|   null|
|test:2|test1:subtest2| 18|  c13|0.00203|
+------+--------------+---+-----+-------+
```

### use reduce()

When there are many unique keys in the json strings, use reduce function to create `df_new`:

```
from functools import reduce     

df_new = reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y)
          , [ df1.select('col1', F.lit(k).alias('col2'), F.explode(F.col(k)).alias('arr')) for k in my_keys ]
         ).select('col1', 'col2', 'arr.*')
```

Comment: Beatiful! Thanks a lot for this!