# Parsing a Type 4 Nested Parquet and flattening/Explode JSON values in a column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, nested, parquet, scd

I am relatively new to Pyspark. And for orchestration I use Databricks.

[Just FYI: My source Parquet holds a SCD Type 4 dataset where the Current Snapshot and History of it is maintained in a Single row, where the Current Snapshot is in Parquet individual Columns while the History Snapshot is within a Columns as a JSON Array.]

Believe my solution could be the one used in the below link and just want to expand that solution to work for me (I am not able to comment on that post as i believe my problem even same is different)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409454/casting-a-column-to-json-dict-and-flattening-json-[values-in-a-column-in-pyspark/56409889#56409889][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409454/casting-a-column-to-json-dict-and-flattening-json-%5Bvalues-in-a-column-in-pyspark/56409889#56409889%5D%5B1%5D)
Reference courtesies : @Gingerbread,@Kafels

And tried to use the resolution in that one, but getting some error

Here's how my dataframe looks like:

```
|HISTORY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:|
|[{"HASH_KEY":"LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==","SOURCE_KEY":"AAAAA","ATTR1":"FSDF CC 10 ml  ","DATE":"2021-06-11"}, {"HASH_KEY":"LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==","SOURCE_KEY":"AAAAA","ATTR1":"BBB CC   ","DATE":"2021-03-11"}, {"HASH_KEY":"LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==","SOURCE_KEY":"AAAAA","ATTR1":"BBB DD   ","DATE":"2021-02-27"}]|
|[{"HASH_KEY":"BK08ZMe/1UTHsenUAOMUwQ==","SOURCE_KEY":"BBBBB","ATTR1":"JAMES 50 ml    ","DATE":"2021-03-02"}, {"HASH_KEY":"BK08ZMe/1UTHsenUAOMUwQ==","SOURCE_KEY":"BBBBB","ATTR1":"JAS 50 ml    ","DATE":"2021-02-02"}]                                                                                                  |
|null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
```

The DataFrame Schema is

```
root
 |-- HISTORY: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Desired output is just to flattening JSON values in a column in pyspark

```
|HASH_KEY                |SOURCE_KEY|DATE      |ATTR1           |            
|:-----------------------|:--------:|:--------:|---------------:|
|LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==|AAAAA     |2021-06-11|FSDF CC 10 ml   |  
|LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==|AAAAA     |2021-03-11|BBB CC          |
|LulKYlm1qJaXFRq7oS1X1A==|AAAAA     |2021-02-27|BBB DD          |
|BK08ZMe/1UTHsenUAOMUwQ==|BBBBB     |2021-03-02|JAMES 50 ml     |
|BK08ZMe/1UTHsenUAOMUwQ==|BBBBB     |2021-02-02|JAS 50 ml       |
|CAsaZMe/1UTHsenUasasaW==|BBBBB     |2021-09-11|null            |
```

The code snippet i tried

```
schema = ArrayType(
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("HASH_KEY1", StringType()),
            StructField("SOURCE_KEY1", StringType()),
            StructField("ATTR1X", StringType()),
            StructField("DATE1", TimestampType())
       ]
    )
)


@f.udf(returnType=schema)
def parse_col(column):
updated_values = []

for it in re.finditer(r'[.*?]', column):
    parse = json.loads(it.group())
    for key, values in parse.items():
        for value in values:
            value['HASH_KEY1'] = key
            updated_values.append(value)

return updated_values


df = df \
    .withColumn('tmp', parse_col(f.col('HISTORY'))) \
    .withColumn('tmp', f.explode(f.col('tmp'))) \
    .select(f.col('HASH_KEY'),
            f.col('tmp').HASH_KEY1.alias('HASH_KEY1'),
            f.col('tmp').SOURCE_KEY1.alias('SOURCE_KEY1'),
            f.col('tmp').ATTR1X.alias('ATTR1X'),
            f.col('tmp').DATE1.alias('DATE1'))

df.show()
```

The following is the result i got

```
|HASH_KEY1|SOURCE_KEY1|ATTR1X|DATE1|
|:-------:|:---------:|:----:|----:|
|         |           |      |     |
|         |           |      |     |
|:-------:|:---------:|:----:|----:|
```

I am having trouble in getting the expected output
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Spark 2.0 + .

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your desired output only contains rows extracted from the HISTORY column except for the last one. What is the logic here? If its not relevant to your question best to remove it to keep your question to the point.

Comment: Edited the question to satisfy the current need.

Answer (score 0):

Undestood the usage of json_tuple and simplified my approach, where i can directly explode the array into a String and then use json_tuple function to convert into flattened columns

So answer snippet now looks as follow

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,json_tuple

DF_EXPLODE = df \
    .withColumn('Expand', f.explode(f.col('HISTORY'))) \
    .select(f.col('Expand'))


DF_FLATTEN = 
DF_EXPLODE.select("*",json_tuple("Expand","HASH_KEY").alias("HASH_KEY")) \
          .select("*",json_tuple("Expand","SOURCE_KEY").alias("SOURCE_KEY"))\
          .select("*",json_tuple("Expand","DATE").alias("DATE"))\
          .select("*",json_tuple("Expand","ATTR1").alias("ATTR1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked on my initial PySpark Looping approach and following is the code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

DF_DIM2 = DF_DIM.withColumn("sizer",size(col('HISTORY'))).sort("sizer",ascending=False)
max_len = DF_DIM2.select('sizer').take(1)[0][0]
print(max_len)
expanded_df = DF_DIM.select(['*'] + [col('HISTORY')[i].alias(f'HISTORY_{i}') for i in range(max_len)])
original_cols = [i for i in expanded_df.columns if 'HISTORY_' not in i ]

cols_exp = [i for i in expanded_df.columns if 'HISTORY_' in i]

schema = StructType([ 
StructField("HASH_KEY",StringType(),True), 
StructField("SOURCE_KEY",StringType(),True), 
StructField("DATE", StringType(), True),
StructField("ATTR1",StringType(),True)
 ])

final_df = expanded_df.select([from_json(i,schema).alias(i) for i in cols_exp])
```

Did some use case testing where joined a 3.72Billion Fact Parquet with 390k Type4 Nested Dimension Parquet and it took 2.5 mins while the Explode option took over 4 mins.
The Explode Option is exploding each of Type4 records multiplied by the times dimension had its changes recorded in the History column. So on an averag if every dimension changed 10 times. Then 390k*10=3.9M records are used in memory to join with the fact leading to more processing times.